# Why do I just get a black screen if I disconnect a DVI monitor and then reconnect it with Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, monitor, dvi

I have one monitor that I use for both my PC (via VGA) and my Linux machine (via DVI). I just use it for one computer at a time, by pulling out the not needed cable and plugging in the required one.

But when I unplug the DVI, after starting Linux, and then plug it back in, I just get a black screen and I have to reboot the Linux machine to get anything to happen.

How can I get it to work properly? ( I don't get this issue reconnecting to my Windows PC)

Comment: it's always interesting which version of ubuntu you are using

Comment: Im using latest version of Xbuntu

Comment: What Graphics Card are you using, and with which driver?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the Linux box via VGA? Different results?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

- system settings
- Brightness & Lock

Switch "Turn screen off when inactive for" to "Never"

[image: Never switch off]

For Xubuntu :

```
Go to "Power Manager"
Tab "On AC"
Tab "Monitor".
Set "Switch off display when computer is inactive" to never
```

Comment: I'm using latest version of Xubuntu - I couldn't find that option but I did find the similar Light Locker and also Power Manager. I changed all settings to Never, unplugged DVI cable expecting that it was solved but no change, back to blank screen :(